# Call methods on mustache variable in a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have a mustache template and I would like to call some function on the mustache variables ({{name}} in this case). Specifically, I want to call toLowerCase() method on the name variable.

```
<tbody>
  <script id="mytemplate" type="text/template">
    {{#cat}}
      <tr data-index="{{age}}-{{name}}"></tr>
    {{/cat}}
  </script>
</tbody>
```

I tried looking in the mustache docs but I couldn't find out how to do this. I tried doing

1. `<tr data-index="{{age}}-{{name.toLowerCase()}}"></tr>`
2. `<tr data-index="{{age}}-{{name}}.toLowerCase()"></tr>`

But I'm not getting what I expect. I render the template with this code which gets triggered on document ready.

```
$(function() {
      $.getJSON('/cats.json', function(data){
        var template = $("#mytemplate").html();
        var view     = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $("tbody").html(view);
      });
  })
```

Comment: Explain the 'not working has expected' part...just by seeing your code, you should try to lowercase the names before rendering the data on the template ;)

Comment: not working as in - its not rendering the name in lower case. Im sure Im doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to pass the [function](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#functions) as part of the data, like so:

```
$(function() {
      $.getJSON('/cats.json', function(data){
        data.lower = function () {
          return function (text, render) {
             //wrong line return render(text.toLowerCase());
             return render(text).toLowerCase();
          }
        };
        var template = $("#mytemplate").html();
        var view     = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $("tbody").html(view);
      });
  })
```

and the template:

```
<tr data-index="{{age}}-{{#lower}}{{name}}{{/lower}}"></tr>
```

Comment: damn, i need more coffee. I saw that part of the readme. dont know why I didnt implement it though!